# How to set dropdown on hover in this templete boostrap4

Tags: hover, navbar, dropdown, menubar

[I Use this template, build with boostrap4](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-heroic-features/archive/v4-dev.zip)

Can you help me to add Hover DropDown Menubar in this above template ?

I update index.html file with some code to show Dropdown menubar, now its shown, but I need to show menu on hover.

Here Is Code:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarExample" aria-controls="navbarExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="img/km-logo.png" style="margin-bottom:5px;" width="60%" height="auto" alt="kmwebsoft.com logo"></a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse dropdown" id="navbarExample">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
          <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">Action</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">Another action</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <span class="text-primary"></span>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </nav>
```

Can you suggest any idea ?   I apply menu on AboutUs temporary.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to use javascript or jquery to do this.bind event on the menu item where you want dropdown menu.

Comment: contact me on FB
facebook.com/kmwebsoft